# PrimeFaces 6.1 timeline dragdrop example from the showcase

Tags: primefaces, timeline

I am trying to run the PrimeFaces 6.1 timeline dragdrop example from the showcase. I can drag the event but can't drop it in the timeline. Has anyone encountered this problem? I also upgraded the jquery version to 2.2.4. but to no avail.

Comment: You are correct. For 6.1 it does not work. I debugged it and the onDrop method is never called.

Comment: It works for me in the current online showcase with the 'current' 6.2-SNAPSHOT. Tried 6.2-Snapshot? Checked the issuelist?